# How can I execute common code post every method in scala

Tags: scala, design-patterns

I have a base trait which contains some operations

```
trait BaseOperations {

  def read(path: String): Data
  
  def write(path: String, data: Data): Boolean

  def exists(path: String): Boolean

}
```

Now I have specific implementations which extends this base trait. As part of metric collection I want to count how many times any method in the trait is called. Current implementation is:

```
object LocalFileSystem extends BaseOperations {

  var counter: Int = 0
  
  override def read(path: String): Data = {
    //do something
    counter+=1
    return data
  }

}
```

Instead of incrementing for every method call in every specific implementation is there any better approach I can take by moving this to trait

Answer (score 1):

Metric collection should be done outside your system through a tracing system. But, anyways, yes, you can do something like this:

```scala
trait BaseOperations {
  private[this] var count: Int = 0

  protected def readImpl(path: String): Data
  final def read(path: String): Data = {
    counter += 1
    readImpl(path)
  }
}
```

The same with all other methods.